# Maximum execution time of 300 seconds in Xampp on Windows

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have changed `php.ini` settings and `max timeout` in `http-default.conf` under apache but still I get the following error:

```
Maximum execution timeout of 300 seconds
```

I have even added `set_time_limit` and `ini_set` to the php script but still I get this error.

How do I resolve this?

Note:

I tried the options in [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680572/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-300-seconds-exceeded).

Comment: Do you happen to be on a shared host provider that prevents setting the maximum execution higher? Also check if any PHP files are being unintentionally loaded in via `auto_prepend_file`.

Comment: Maybe you should just make a php info file with code like: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and check what the timeout is set to? Next check which ini file it's actually using etc etc

Comment: The first rule in programming (and pc issues in general) is debugging and getting information instead of just changing stuff and hope for the best! Get PHP to tell you what its settings are, which ini file it's loading, stuff like that. If you know what it's doing you also know where to actually fix it.

Comment: I have got the info from phpinfo too..and I have set both too to 86400 but the script is getting timed out at 300 seconds

Comment: Does phpinfo tell you the timeout is set to 86400 seconds?

Comment: yes it has..I am able to see master as local values as 86400

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change Maximum Execution Time

**php.ini**

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

**From Code**

Start your code with,

```
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', 3600);
```

**.htaccess**

```
php_value max_execution_time 3600
```

No matter which option you choose, restart Apache service.

Answer (score 3):

Conditions:

If you are using phpMyadmin to import large sql files and you have increased max_execution time, max file upload limit and everything needed
And If none of the above answers work for you come here

Go to your server (xampp or wamp) folder, in my case here is the relative path to the file that I need to modify: C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php

```
/**
  * maximum execution time in seconds (0 for no limit)
  * 
  * @global integer $cfg['ExecTimeLimit']
  * by defautlt 300 is the value
  * change it to 0 for unlimited 
  * time is seconds
  * Line 709 for me
*/
 $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

use below thing and i think will work

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini you must check mysql.connect_timeout either.
So, for example, change it to:

```
mysql.connect_timeout = 1000
```

That time will be always counted in seconds