# GOOGLE SQL, import sql timeout on 300secs

Tags: google-cloud-sql

This is in the manual
if your imports or exports might exceed 24 hours in duration, see Working with long-running import and export processes for more information.
The import for a sql file should be 24 hours,

i get the following error after 300 secs:

mysql_query You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
 **Fatal error**: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded i

How can i set it to longer?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680572/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-300-seconds-exceeded

Comment: If you are importing large records, please use cloudsql-import tool: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/import-export?hl=en#longproc

Answer (score 1):

Big mistake from my side. The xport files contained a fault line. All works perfectly, importing files over 3Gig is no problem.