# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\modules\phpmy

Tags: php

I got this error in EasyPhp when I try to access to EasyPhp MyAdmin to see my database.

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\modules\phpmyadmin414x150807154856\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php on line 285

Please Help !

Comment: Please give us more details and show what code causes the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680572/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-300-seconds-exceeded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following at the top of your `php` script

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(1);
```

---

[set_time_limit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)  - Limits the maximum execution time in seconds (0 is unlimited)
[ignore_user_abort](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)  - Set whether a client disconnect should abort script execution