# PHP read mail not working in time

Tags: php, email

i am trying to read mail header.
i received more than 400 daily to whom i have to read,
my execution time is 300sec, it shows me

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

is there is any other way to read header fast,
help me to solve the issue
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680572/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-300-seconds-exceeded)

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass execution time with :

```
set_time_limit(0); // unlimited execution time.
```

If you are searching a fast IMAP Mail Client you can use :

https://github.com/SSilence/php-imap-client

Answer (score 0):

Increase Time Heim`php.ini` argument `set_time_limit()`.
Exemple:
Change to

```
set_time_limit(0)
```

Restart the server