# Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in php

Tags: php, curl

I have encountered this error when trying to run a code.

`Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\abc_app\application\libraries\Curl.php on line 329`

line 329 is `$this->response = curl_exec($this->session);`.

After googling I changed below in php.ini,

```
max_execution_time = 90000
max_input_time = -1
memory_limit = 1280M
```

But error still come. Please help me.

Comment: You can even directly change it in PHP using `ini_set('max_execution_time', 90000);`

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680572/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-300-seconds-exceeded

Comment: Did you add the directives in the correct section, or just add them at the end?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164930/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded)

Comment: Did you really make that typo in the php settings your code above shows?

Comment: Did you really restart your http server process after changing the php settings?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a underscope in variable define:

```
max_execution_time = 90000
```

Comment: Sorry I am new. Do you want remove my answer?

Comment: No, totally fine. Simply always remember to put a little text, plain code answers are not good answers. Doesn't need to be a lot of text, what you've done is totally enough.