# phpmyadmin large sql file import issue

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I am trying to import my SQL file which is of 89Mb....the below-mentioned error is coming, kindly help.

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in
> C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Token.php on line 257

The below-mentioned configuration is set in the `php.ini` file.

```
max_execution_time=300000000
max_input_time=300000000
memory_limit=512M
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please only tag a single RDBMS.

Comment: A similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680572/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-300-seconds-exceeded).

Comment: yes it is MySQL

Comment: Check if you're running PHP in safe mode, because it ignores all time exec settings when on that.

Comment: I would not use phpmyadmi  to import large files.